# Comparing two arrays and pushing the result to new array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two arrays that are solely filled with strings. I am trying to compare the values in the strings and then push the strings to an empty array.

```
goupId = [
{'1','2','3','4'}]
homeGroups = 
[{'2','3', '4','1'}]
sameId =[];
```

this is my logic

```
compare: function(groupId, homeGroups) {
                this.groupId.forEach((e1)=>this.homeGroups.foreach((e2)=>{
                    if(e1 === e2){
                        this.sameId.push(e1)
                    }
                }
            ));
            }
```

I get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: You need to provide enough code to reproduce your issue. It's not clear why you are using `this.groupId` when `groupId` is being passed as a function parameter.

Comment: Start by posting valid code, `{'1','2','3','4'}` is not a valid object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the `this.` when referencing `groupID` and `homeGroups` as they are not member variables. You can learn more about `this` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Your code will end up looking like this.

```
compare: function(groupId, homeGroups) {
   groupId.forEach(e1 => 
      homeGroups.foreach(e2 => {
         if(e1 === e2){
            this.sameId.push(e1)
         }
      }
   ));
}
```